# JTextPane remove background set via setCharacterAttributes

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane, styleddocument

I working on my own editor, for which I want to add a background colour to text a user might search for. Finding the text and setting a background colour is not a problem, the problem is how can I remove the background colour when the focus (highlight) is moved?

This sets the highlight:

```
int findPos = /* start position of user search text */
int findLength = /* length of user search text */

SimpleAttributeSet highlight = new SimpleAttributeSet();
StyleConstants.setBackground(highlight, Color.CYAN);
StyledDocument doc = jtextpane.getStyleDocument();
doc.setCharacterAttributes(findPos, findLength, highlight, false);
```

But how can I remove the highlight again, without affecting the foreground colours? Because the editor supports syntax highlighting, the foreground colour could be anything.

The only thing I can think of is to simply reset the entire `StyledDocument` and then run my highlight method over the entire thing again ... but that seems to be a terribly inefficient idea.

Comment: Instead of playing with attributes, maybe use the `Highlighter` of the text pane.  This will allow you to add/remove highlights independently.

Comment: Hi @camickr thank you, from my quick test just now, it seems to work a charm :)